# Angular unit testing nested functions

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I my angular project I have a service1 that depends on service 2. Service1 is sending a rather complex function for callbackSuccess into service2

service2.js

```
 this.getData = function (url, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
```

I'm not sure whether there is much point unit testing service2 and I should rather focus on service1 since most of the logic is contained in there. Can someone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Should you test `service2`?

If `service2` is obviously correct because it is so simple you can inspect it - then you probably do not need tests for it. However if it is any more complex then that, then you probably want to test it.

I can see that it must be doing at least 3 things:

1. does *something* with `url`
2. calls success callback only if operation was successful, and calls it with all the correct parameters based upon output of operation
3. calls error callback only if operation was not successful, and calls it with all the correct parameters based upon the output (such as error codes and messages)

To me, this amount of work would lead me to add some tests - haven't even though about exception handling for instance... The testing of it, since it is simple, should also be simple.

### Testing `service1`

If `service1` contains a complicated callback then it definitely should be tested. Make sure that callback is accessible from your tests so you can test it thoroughly in isolation from the rest of what `service1` might be doing before passing it off to `service2`.

### Conclusion

Ultimately you are asking an opinion question, and one that relies upon a lot of information about your codebase, goals, and deadlines which we do not know. My best answer is: test `service2`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply create a spy on the function in `service2` or mock out `service2` completely.

```
var data_spy = spyOn(service2, 'getData').andCallFake(
    function(url, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
        callbackSuccess(mock_data); // Mock the data somewhere
    }
);
```

Using this is a good idea since it removes the dependence on `service2` functionality in your test. Although you should still consider testing `service2`.

Some other advice. This model seems to lend itself very well to promises, since there is a resolve and reject callback. I recommend you take a look at [$q documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

Hope this helped!